# How to apply values to pattern for all combinations in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching, combinations

I have following 2 dimensional array input:

```
 var arr = [ 
        ['A', ['Sun','Moon']],
        ['B', ['Cat','Dog']],
        ['C', ['John','Peter','Zora']]
 ];
```

Using that input, I want all combinations applied to a given pattern in javascript:

The placeholders in the pattern are in following format: $(*name*)

*Here are some sample patterns with result:*

```
 var pattern1 = "$(A) / $(A)";
 /* Expected Result
    "Sun / Sun"
    "Sun / Moon"
    "Moon / Sun"
    "Moon / Moon"
 */

 var pattern2 = "$(A)--$(B)";
/* Expected Result
    "Sun--Cat"
    "Sun--Dog"
    "Moon--Cat"
    "Moon--Dog"
*/

 var pattern3 = "$(C) + $(B)";
/* Expected Result
    "John + Cat"
    "John + Dog"
    "Peter + Cat"
    "Peter + Dog"
    "Zora + Cat"
    "Zora + Dog"    
*/

  var pattern4 = "$(A) - $(A) * ( $(B) + $(C) )";
/* Expected Result
    "Sun -  Sun * ( Cat + John )"
    "Sun -  Sun * ( Cat + Peter )"
    "Sun -  Sun * ( Cat + Zora )"
    "Sun -  Sun * ( Dog + John )"
    "Sun -  Sun * ( Dog + Peter )"
    "Sun -  Sun * ( Dog + Zora )"
    "Sun -  Moon * ( Cat + John )"
    "Sun -  Moon * ( Cat + Peter )"
    "Sun -  Moon * ( Cat + Zora )"
    "Sun -  Moon * ( Dog + John )"
    "Sun -  Moon * ( Dog + Peter )"
    "Sun -  Moon * ( Dog + Zora )"
    "Moon -  Sun * ( Cat + John )"
    "Moon -  Sun * ( Cat + Peter )"
    "Moon -  Sun * ( Cat + Zora )"
    "Moon -  Sun * ( Dog + John )"
    "Moon -  Sun * ( Dog + Peter )"
    "Moon -  Sun * ( Dog + Zora )"
    "Moon -  Moon * ( Cat + John )"
    "Moon -  Moon * ( Cat + Peter )"
    "Moon -  Moon * ( Cat + Zora )"
    "Moon -  Moon * ( Dog + John )"
    "Moon -  Moon * ( Dog + Peter )"
    "Moon -  Moon * ( Dog + Zora )"
*/
```

The pattern can be any combination (with repeating placeholders) and any length.

Can someone help me with an algorithm in javascript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to do this.

First you have to extract the names from the string. You can do this with a regular expression:

```
var regex = /\$\(([A-Z])\)/g,
    names = [], match;

while(match = regex.exec(pattern)) {
    names.push(match[1]);
}
```

Then you pass this list plus a mapping of your values to a function which iterates over the names recursively:

```
function create_combinations(pattern, names, map, index) {
    index = index || 0;
    var name = names[index],
        values = map[name],
        needle = "$(" + name + ")",
        combinations = [],
        sub;

    if (index === names.length - 1) {
        for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; i++) {
            combinations.push(pattern.replace(needle, values[i]));
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; i++) {
            sub = pattern.replace(needle, values[i]);
            combinations = combinations.concat(create_combinations(sub, names, map, index + 1));
        }
    }
    return combinations;
}
```

This requires that your data structure will be an object:

```
var map = { 
    'A': ['Sun','Moon'],
    'B': ['Cat','Dog'],
    'C': ['John','Peter','Zora']
};
```

Then you call the function with

```
create_combinations(pattern, names, map);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/dT4b9/)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the placeholders one at a time.

Example: Start with the pattern in an array:

```
["$(A) / $(A)"]
```

Replace the first placeholder and create strings for all combinations:

```
["Sun / $(A)", "Moon / $(A)"]
```

Replace the next placeholder in each string and create string for all combinations:

```
["Sun / Sun", "Sun / Moon", "Moon / Sun", "Moon / Moon"]
```

Repeat until there are no more placeholders.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/qGBpg/